# Incorrect text positioning in UITableViewCell in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have created a UITableView with two cells, username and password using the code below.

I have included a screenshot of the output the **first time** the view loads (the expected output) and the **second time** the view is shown (the incorrect output)

[image: Expected result] [image: Incorrect result on second load]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Login Ident"];   

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        loginId = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        loginId .placeholder = @"Email address";
        loginId .autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [loginId setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = loginId;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        password.placeholder = @"Password";
        password.secureTextEntry = YES;
        password.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [password setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = password;
    }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    loginId.delegate = self;
    password.delegate = self;

    [loginId setText:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount]];
    [password setText:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData]];

    [loginId addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(textFieldReturn:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    [password addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(textFieldReturn:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:loginId];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:password];

    }


    return cell;  
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

My UITextField declarations

```
UITextField *loginId; 
UITextField *password;
```

If anybody is able to help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it.

**With changes**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the code where you create the text fields inside the if (cell == nil) {} since otherwise you could be adding a second textfield to a cell that's already been created previously. If that doesn't fix the issue post back.

Also, remove:

```
[_tableView addSubview:loginId];
[_tableView addSubview:password];
```

You shouldn't add views that are meant for the cells to the tableview. And instead of making it the accessoryView of the cell, add them to the contentView

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:loginId];
```

See chat below for full resolution of the issue.

Comment: Good tip - I tried this but it didn't make any difference. The "Password" text still appeared in the same position on second load.

Comment: Just noticed some other issues with your code. Added stuff to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again Philippe. I updated my answer with the new output I get from making these changes. Slightly different positioning now!

Comment: Make sure to remove the cell.accessoryView calls, accessoryView is only meant for the > type widgets.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6320/discussion-between-nick-and-philippe-sabourin)

Comment: I just remembered. The reason I did it this way is that static cells are only available for UITableViewController and I'm using UIViewController.

Comment: Why are you using a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController?

Comment: Anyways, you can do it with prototype cells instead of static cells if you wanted.