# Incorrect text positioning in UITableViewCell in Xcode when creating cells programatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created a UITableView with two cells, username and password using the code below.  I am doing this programatically as static cells can't be used in a UIViewController (where this table must reside)

I have included a screenshot of the output the **first time** the view loads (the expected output) and the **second time** the view is shown (the incorrect output)

[image: Expected result] [image: Incorrect result on second load]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Login Ident"];   

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        loginId = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        loginId .placeholder = @"Email address";
        loginId .autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [loginId setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = loginId;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        password.placeholder = @"Password";
        password.secureTextEntry = YES;
        password.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [password setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = password;
    }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    loginId.delegate = self;
    password.delegate = self;

    [loginId setText:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount]];
    [password setText:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData]];

    [loginId addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(textFieldReturn:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    [password addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(textFieldReturn:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:loginId];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:password];

    //[_tableView addSubview:loginId];
    //[_tableView addSubview:password];

    }


    return cell;  
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

My UITextField declarations

```
UITextField *loginId; 
UITextField *password;
```

If anybody is able to help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect text positioning in UITableViewCell in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705623/incorrect-text-positioning-in-uitableviewcell-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are having issues with your cell reuse.

Here is how I would do it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Login Ident";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (nil == cell) {

        // Within this if statement do any work that is not going to change over the lifetime of the cell.

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];   

        // You was setting `selectionStyle` on every run so it should be 
        // safe to set here once
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 
    }

    const NSInteger textFieldTag = 10; // <- No special meaning, just non-zero

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:textFieldTag];

    // I've followed a similar pattern to the cell reuse above for creating the textfield
    // This ensures that we only create a textfield once per cell and then reuse it
    if (nil == textField) {
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        textField .autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField.clearButtonMode     = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.delegate            = self;
        textField.tag = textFieldTag;
        [cell addSubview:textField];
    }

    // Next do any work to configure the different cells

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        textField.placeholder = @"Email address";
        cell.accessoryView = loginId;
        textField = textField;
        loginId = textField;

    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        textField.placeholder = @"Password";
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        cell.accessoryView = password;
        password = textField;

    }

    // ... rest of your work

    return cell;  
}
```

Comment: 1. You never set loginId 2. Your reuse identifiers are not done correctly (<code>const NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FooBar";</code>) 3. Reusing text fields is hardly necessary!

Comment: What is the advantage of using `const NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FooBar";`. Either way seems valid to me (I could be wrong). If you don't reuse the `UITextField` then you would either have to forget cell reuse completely or remove the `UITextField` from the cell and create a new one on every `tableView :cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: const ensures the object is always the same. The point I am getting at though is that you have two different reuse identifiers going on - Cell and Login Ident (also done by the OP).

Comment: I see what you mean I copied and pasted the OP's code and assumed that they just wrote `@"cell"` both times, but obviously not, good catch.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the answer. This didn't work for me and both cells appeared blank.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally redeclared `UITextField *textField` within the `if (nil == textField) {` it should work now.

Comment: That fixed one problem :) Now when a modal is shown in front of the view and hidden, I get an exception when 'password' is tapped.

Comment: My problem was trivial. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a issue because of the cell reusing. you need to change your cell a bit: add a textLabel in the `if(cell==nil)` branch, but configure it as username or password outside of the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the section:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if( cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Login Ident"];</code>
```

should be

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Login Ident";
UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if( cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];</code>
```

Secondly, creating your text fields should be done outside the `if (cell == nil)` section.

Comment: Can someone please fix the formatting - I'm on a mobile device and it is a real pain? Thanks

Comment: The difference for the cell reuse identifier is pretty minimal, in fact I'm not sure there is any real difference? (I'd be happy to be proved wrong). As for creating the `UITextField` outside of `if` this is not necessarily true, if every cell has the same view hierarchy it would be perfectly valid to build it once within this `if` statement.

Comment: Yes but if cells are reused then their text fields are not going to be set e.g. Placeholder text

Comment: No probs for the edit. Well the cell is reused but then configured after, which is why the configuration code is placed outside of the `if (nil == cell) { ... }`

Comment: I know, that's why I said to do that! Reusing the cell saves on some allocations, so it does help, albeit not much!